Допустимо ли тире сразу после точки?
Это вопрос волнует меня с детства. Помню, в совсем раннем возрасте в классической литературе я почти точно встречал следующую конструкцию: два самостоятельных предложения, стоящие друг за другом, при этом второе является в каком-то смысле выводом из первого и начинается с тире.
Я очень давно такое не встречал и не знаю, где раздобыть настоящие примеры из литературы. Однако, если попробовать на скорую руку сконструировать какой-нибудь пример самому, получится что-то типа такого:
«Горящие балки начали постепенно осыпаться и падать. — Мы больше не могли там находиться».
Еще я помню, что когда я давным давно сам попробовал применить это в каком-то сочинении, учительница зачеркнула это красным цветом и поставила рядом знак вопроса — больше я так никогда не писал. Мне интересно, кто в итоге был прав. Может, у меня какие-то ложные воспоминания по поводу литературы, которую я читал в детстве, или тогда я просто наткнулся на кого-то с таким авторским стилем.
Спасибо!

Вы же понимаете, что всякий знак не может возникнуть из ничего, т.е. случайно. Ваш сконструированный пример тому иллюстрация. Ну и воспоминаниям детства, даже если они почти точные, не стоит всецело доверять .

В качестве авторского знака, если вы сможете его оправдать), ну и в переключении между внешней речью и внутренней.

Кто вам разрешит?  Это совершенно невозможно)  Пользователи не поймут вашу авторскую идею)   Вы переключились,  а они нет.  Лучше многоточие поставить.

Пользователи определяют, как писать автору - о временя, о нравы!

А вы для кого пишете,  сами для себя?  Тогда да,  можно и собственные знаки препинания придумать)  Звездочку, решетку или еще что)   Я и то думаю, что мало у нас знаков препинания.   Может, в других языках  есть какие?

@Арчи  Я поддерживаю вашу идею напомнить участникам форума о вопросах. оставшихся без ответа.  Вот и здесь:  трое поговорили, обменялись репликами и разошлись.  Почему?  Так  если даешь ответ, то ответственности много)) Тогда нужно как в игре "Что, где, когда?". Обсуждают, сомневаются, но через минуту один участник отвечает, даже если ответ неясен.  Вот пусть и отвечает кто-нибудь из них)

Да-а, нехорошо как-то получается... а вопросы и не самые скучные

Вообще, помимо пунктуации в оформлении прямой речи, что-то подобное можно встретить в "Лолите":

Покачала головой чрезвычайно решительно. Считала, что уже поздно
устраивать скандал – и что всё равно я никогда не поверю невероятному,
невероятнейшему. – Я встал, говоря, что мне пора, привет мужу, приятно
было повидать её

По мнению И. В. Труфановой, это пример окказионального использования тире, сигнализирующий о переходе к несобственно-прямой речи и наоборот. И, скорее всего, в вашей памяти как раз могло всплыть нечто подобное. Но это не для вашего примера. А в вашем тексте уместна либо точка, либо запятая с тире.

Отвечу я, вряд ли желающие найдутся))
Горящие балки начали постепенно осыпаться и падать, — мы больше не могли там находиться.
Пояснение
Ставим единый знак — запятую и тире. Это знак универсальный и применяется довольно часто. С одной стороны, он обозначает значительно увеличенную паузу, а с другой — перелом конструкции, переход к следующей теме.
Если поставить просто тире, то будет обозначена более тесная взаимообусловленность двух сообщений, а по смыслу это следующее предложение.
Использование прописной буквы после тире правилами не предусмотрено.
